# MAUI: floating element that transitions across pages

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

I need to create floating view element that sits on top of the page and transistions between pages.

This quick example: the pink "Paw" button on top of the page, same button on next page.

[image]

One option that I found is to use **ControlTemplate** on ALL pages and append new button each time it is opened. But I want it to be single across pages or attached to my MainPage (FlyoutPage).

*My real goal is to make small panel with ongoing call, that shows timer and hang/mute buttons, so user could use application and browse pages and menus, but that panel would be always on top.*

Need any advice or best practice.

Comment: For this feature, you can create a [Feature Request](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose) here.

Comment: Feature will be implemented in interval from "not soon" to "never". I wonder how to do it yourself, or, at least, in which direction start looking. What are best practices and what other people do in these scenarios.